# Unable to download file

Tags: html

I am trying to create a portfolio for myself, for that reason, I added a download link for my resume.

**This is the code**

```
        <a href="smammar resume.pdf" download=""></a>
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Resume
    </div>
```

When the link is clicked, nothing happens.
What I want is that the download link should display a pop-up of asking the user to download the file.

**Here is the link for Github repo**
https://github.com/SMAmmar/my_portfolio

Comment: when i started with html, i made the same mistake. don't wrap a link in a button.

Comment: what should  I do then

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a button, use the `<a>` tag itself

```
p>Download Resume</p>
<a class="btn" href="smammar resume.pdf" download="">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download
</a>
```

Add necessary styles to the anchor tag to make it look like a button if required